# The Answer Question Wizard

Tags: feature-request, answers, low-quality-posts, new-users, not-an-answer

After having lost way too many hours of my life futilely flagging the endless stream of Not An Answer (NAA) posts we get in the [SOBotics chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111347/sobotics) (Please provide your code, I'm having this problem too, Are there any updates?, Thanks, etc.), I thought that we could have an Answer Question Wizard that is akin to the existing [ask-question-wizard](/questions/tagged/ask-question-wizard). New users who have not posted a well-received answer before will be strongly encouraged to use the wizard (if not required to do so), while other users could choose to use it if they wished.

It would start out something like this:

> My primary purpose in posting this answer is to:
>
> - Advertise a product or service
> - Ask for clarification regarding the problem
> - Ask for updates on the problem
> - Share a helpful link
> - Thank another poster for a helpful solution
> - Provide my own solution to the problem
> - Make an off-hand comment

If the user picks anything other than the "correct" option, appropriate guidance will be given as to why an answer is not suitable, and suggesting more appropriate ways to accomplish it.

Will this stop *all* NAA answers? Of course not. What I do hope is that it could substantially stanch the flow of posts from naive new users who simply don't know that answers cannot be used to comment, flooding our site with stuff that needs moderation attention.

Comment: Related https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/285924/320339

Comment: Personally I believe there is no need for wizard, instead code similar to Natty's code can automatically alert and try to stop user posting. Maybe later I will take time and try to elaborate this in an answer

Comment: A bit of a nitpick, but a wouldn't have the option call it an "off-hand" comment. Some of the people using the answer field to comment feel that whatever they have to say is important enough that we ought to make an exception for it. They're going to keeps seeing it that way if we make it look like the rule is about unimportant comments instead of all comments full stop.